# f(g(x)) has a degree divisible by n

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $f(x)$ a irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over a field $F$. Let $g(x)$ be a polynomial in $F[x]$. Prove that every irreducible factor of the composition $f(g(x))$ has a degree which is divisible by $n$.

I don't know even how to begin. I really need help. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Suppose $h$ is an irreducible factor of $f \circ g$, and $\alpha$ is a root of $h$ (in some extension field). Then $g(\alpha)$ is a root of $f$, and so, since $f$ is irreducible of degree $n$, $[F(g(\alpha)):F]=n$. Thus $\deg(h)=[F(\alpha):F]=[F(\alpha):F(g(\alpha))]\cdot[F(g(\alpha)):F]$ is divisible by $n$.

Comment: thank you very much for the help. Just one question, why $f(g(\alpha))$ is well-defined?

Comment: @user42912: I'm having trouble seeing the problem. $\alpha$ is an element of an extension field of $F$. $f\circ g$ is a polynomial over $F$, hence defines a function on every extension field. I'm just applying that function to that element.

Comment: Why do we know that $[F(g(\alpha)):F] =n$, particularly why do we know it is an equality? Shouldn't it be an inequality? Namely $[F(g(\alpha)):F] \leq n$

Comment: @user110320: We know $[F(g(\alpha)):F] = n$ because $g(\alpha)$ is a root of $f(X)$, and all fields obtained by adjoining a root of $f(X)$ to $F$ are isomorphic to one another by sending a root $\alpha'$ in $F(\alpha')$, say, to $\alpha''$ in $F(\alpha'')$. In particular, $F(\alpha')$ and $F(\alpha'')$ have the same dimension as $F$-vector spaces.

Comment: so smart approach :)