# exists $f(x)$ irreducible such that $g(f(x))$ is reducible

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

How to prove the following statement?

> In $\mathbb Q[x]$, for any irreducible polynomial $g(x)$, there exists an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ such that $g(f(x))$ is reducible.
>
> (from a [discussion](http://kuing.infinityfreeapp.com/forum.php?mod=redirect&goto=findpost&ptid=11660&pid=56563).
> By searching MSE, I found a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3992840/what-happens-if-fx-is-irreducible-but-fgx-is-reducible))

### Example

Given $g(x) = x^2+1$, there is an irreducible polynomial $f(x) = x^2+3x+3$, and $g(f(x)) = (x^2 + 2x + 2)(x^2 + 4x + 5)$ is reducible.

### Example

Given $g(x) = x^2+x+1$, how to find an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ such that $f(x)^2+f(x)+1$ is reducible?

Comment: It is a cool fact that if $g(x)$ is any polynomial and $c$ is any constant, then the polynomial $g(x+cg(x))$ is divisible by $g(x)$. ([Here is a proof](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2288618p17994784) when the roots of $g(x)$ are distinct; the proof is for $c=1$ but immediately generalizes.) So if any of the polynomials $x+cg(x)$ are irreducible ($c\ne0$) then the answer is yes. In particular, if $g(x)=x^2+x+1$, we can choose $f(x)=x+2g(x)=2x^2+3x+2$ which is irreducible, obtaining $g(f(x)) = g(x)(4x^2+8x+7)$.

Comment: @Greg Simpler: $\bmod \color{#c00}{g(x)}\!:\ \color{#c00}{g(x)\equiv 0}\Rightarrow g(x+c\color{#c00}{g(x)})\equiv g(x)\equiv 0,\,$ as used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1283820/242) to show nonconstant polynomials cannot have only prime values.

Comment: @BillDubuque I agree, that's the proof that I like—though a lot of undergraduates might be unfamiliar with modulo-a-polynomial.

Comment: @Greg But as I show in my [prior link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1283820/242) it can equivalently be proved by the Factor Theorem, i.e. $\,g(\color{#0a0}{x+cg(x)})-g(\color{#c00}x)\,$ is divisible by $\color{#0a0}{x+cg(x)} - \color{#c00}x = cg(x)$ thus $\,g(x)\mid g(x+cg(x))\ \ $